# osixia/openldap Docker image does not connect to my container

Tags: asp.net, docker, openldap

I'm trying to connect to osixia/openldap Docker image in order to authenticate users.

The thing is that I'm making the logic of the login in ASP.NET, and my code works fine and connects to the LDAP server. The problem is when I build the Docker image of the code. The docker image doesn't connect to the LDAP server.  Also I use the  osixia/phpldapadmin for registering the users, and it works fine.

I apprecite any advice.

Here is the dokcer-compose I'm using.

```
version: '3'


services:
  authms:
    image: authms
    container_name: authms_l
    ports:
        - "7049:80"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: "http://+"
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
    links:
      - wings-ldap


  wings-ldap:
    image: osixia/openldap:1.1.8
    container_name: wings-ldap
    environment:
      COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT: 200
      LDAP_LOG_LEVEL: "256"
      LDAP_ORGANISATION: "Wings"
      LDAP_DOMAIN: "wings.co"
      LDAP_BASE_DN: ""
      LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD: "admin"
      LDAP_CONFIG_PASSWORD: "config"
      LDAP_READONLY_USER: "false"
      LDAP_BACKEND: "hdb"
      LDAP_TLS: "true"
      LDAP_TLS_CRT_FILENAME: "ldap.crt"
      LDAP_TLS_KEY_FILENAME: "ldap.key"
      LDAP_TLS_CA_CRT_FILENAME: "ca.crt"
      LDAP_TLS_ENFORCE: "false"
      LDAP_TLS_CIPHER_SUITE: "SECURE256:-VERS-SSL3.0"
      LDAP_TLS_PROTOCOL_MIN: "3.1"
      LDAP_TLS_VERIFY_CLIENT: "demand"
      LDAP_REPLICATION: "false"
      LDAP_REMOVE_CONFIG_AFTER_SETUP: "true"
      LDAP_SSL_HELPER_PREFIX: "ldap"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/ldap
      - /etc/ldap/slapd.d
      - /container/service/slapd/assets/certs/
    ports:
      - "389:389"
      - "636:636"
    hostname: "wings.co"

  phpldapadmin:
    image: osixia/phpldapadmin:latest
    container_name: ldap_client_w
    environment:
      PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS: "wings-ldap"
      PHPLDAPADMIN_HTTPS: "false"
    ports:
      - "8095:80"
    links:
      - wings-ldap
```

And here is how I'm conecting in

```
string ldapServer = "wings-ldap";
int ldapPort = 389;
string ldapUserId = "cn=admin";
string ldapPassword = "admin";
string ldapBaseDn = "dc=wings,dc=co";
using (LdapConnection connection =new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(ldapServer, ldapPort))){
connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = false;
connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("cn=admin,dc=wings,dc=co", "admin");

connection.Bind(nc);

string userDn = $"cn={credentials.UserId}," + "ou=sa," + ldapBaseDn;

string userPassword = credentials.Password;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the host your pointing to from `localhost` to `wings-ldap`. `localhost` doesn't mean the same thing inside your docker container as it does when everything is running right on your host machine. The reason that PHPMyAdmin works is because you're `wings-ldap` as the host via the environment variable, `PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS`.

When using docker compose, Docker enables each service inside the same docker network (created automatically for all services inside the same compose file) to resolve each other by their service name (e.g. `wings-ldap`, `authms`, `phpldapadmin`, or whatever else you use as keys in the services dictionary in your yaml file). If you ever change the service name you'll need to update these references accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried with that, unfortunately it still doesn't connect.